# ¿Cómo registrar varias IP con Firebase de Google?

Tags: php, javascript, firebase

Verán tengo un pequeño problema, estoy trabajando con una base de datos usando el servidor de Firebase de Google la función Beta de Firestore.

Bueno lo que sucede es que cree un sistema de encuestas mediante votos, la cual solo permite hacer un voto por cada usuario.

Tengo un campo llamado `IPs` en una tabla echa en Firebase, la cual tienen que registrar cada IP de cada usuario para evitar que voten más de una vez, solo que cada que registra una nueva IP la anterior se borra.

Ya no se ni como hacerle, me perdi completamente :(

Este es mi código Javascript:

```
var db = firebase.firestore();
function setVote(vals) {
    db
    .collection("polls")
    .doc("votes")
    .set(vals)
    .then(function(result) {
        alert(result);
    });
}
setVote({
    IPs: [
        { ip: "<?php echo $ip->address; ?>" }
    ],
    manzana: +2
});
```

También me gustaría verificar que la ip del visitante ya existe en la base de datos y sino existe permitirle votar, solo que no sé cómo hacerlo.

¿Cómo podría lograr eso? Necesito ayuda.

Gracias por su ayuda de ante mano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo ideal para tu situación sería que los usuarios ingresen usando [Firebase Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web), de esa manera te garantizas que cada registro corresponde a un usuario real y que no se puede duplicar. Creo que es un método mas efectivo que filtrar por IP que se modifica cuando el usuario se cambia de ubicación.
En caso de que no quieras que tus usuarios se registren puedes usar [autenticación anónima](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth) para identificar cada dispositivo, pero esto tiene una limitación similar al chequeo por IP, si me conecto con 2 PC voy a poder votar 2 veces.

Lo ideal es solicitar un login (via google, facebook, etc) para evitar que los usuarios tengan que registrarse.

Comment: Y cómo puedo obtener el identificador de cada usuario e ingresarlo en un array multidimensional en Firestore, para saber que usuarios han comentado o dado like a algún post

Comment: Para eso deberias Crear un registro en Firestore por cada usuario, cada vez que un usuario de like agregas en el id de la publicacion en una coleccion de "likes" dentro de cada usuario.